# Eclipse upload program to gdbserver of target

Tags: eclipse, gdb, embedded, gdbserver

I have a small embedded system, and I like to use Eclipse to write/upload/debug programs.

There is only one problem, Eclipse can not upload programs via gdb to gdbserver.

There is support for:

- DataStore
- SSH
- FTP
- Telnet

But they all require extra software on my embedded system.

With gdb you can upload programs to gdbserver of the embedded system.

Does you know if there is some Eclipse support for that? Maybe a plugin?

(I searched 2 days before asking, so it would be great if you can help me out here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the address space where you wish copy the program you can do it from GDB:

from https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html :

> **restore** *filename* [binary] bias *start* *end*
>
> > Restore the contents of file *filename* into memory. The **restore** command can automatically recognize any known bfd file format, except for raw binary. To restore a raw binary file you must specify the optional keyword binary after the *filename*.
> >     If *bias* is non-zero, its value will be added to the addresses contained in the file. Binary files always *start* at address zero, so they will be restored at address *bias*. Other bfd files have a built-in location; they will be restored at offset *bias* from that location.
> >
> > If *start* and/or *end* are non-zero, then only data between file offset *start* and file offset *end* will be restored. These offsets are relative to the addresses in the file, before the *bias* argument is applied.

i imagine it will be possible to connect this functionality to an Eclipse button.

Answer (score 1):

Install C/C++ cross compiling support and C/C++ GDB Hardware debugging plug-in. 
These are in default update sites (just do help->install new software and look under "mobile and device development").

This should let you build and deploy code to your embedded system. You will need to specify the toolchain prefix (project configuration) and the name of your gdb (GDB hardware debugging).

In debugger tab of launch configuration choose "generic tcp/ip device" and enter address and port of running gdbserver.

This tutorial could be useful: http://janaxelson.com/eclipse5.htm

Comment: Installing those plug-ins was a good one. In the tutorial they use ssh. Behind the scene there is an sftp-server on the beagleboard, to which the files get uploaded. I want to upload my files to gdbserver instead of sftp-server.

Comment: I tried it out now, it look you need to use gdb hardware debugging for this scenario. Answer modified.

Comment: No, you do not need to use hardware debugging.

Comment: What alternative do you have in mind? Using regular launch, specifying different gdb binary and scripting connection in .gdbinit?